# jQuery ajax callback never called

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-callback

Javascript code, using jQuery 1.7:

```
$( function() { 
  $.get('/ajax_dummy', function() { alert('foo');  })
});
```

With Firebug I can see that the HTTP GET request is sent and a "hello world" response with code 200 is returned, so everything seems fine. But the callback is never called.

I have no idea what is wrong; this should be so simple, right?

Comment: `$.get()` will fail silently. Switch to using `$.ajax()` with an `error` method and see if that gets run instead. If it does, take a look at the arguments given to to see what's going wrong.

Comment: What type of content comes back from the ajax handler? If it's JSON and the response has malformed JSON it can fail without giving you a clear reason why.

Comment: At quick glance, are you missing a ';' at the end of the get statement?

Comment: @brheal while the semicolon ought to be put in, it is not causing the issue at hand.

Comment: Any JavaScript errors in the console?

Comment: what is the content-type header in the response from server..

Comment: @Dan Herbert: The content type was 'application/json', when I changed to 'plain/text' it worked :) If you would like the points, make an answer.

Comment: @JAAulde: Thanks for the tips about using $.ajax which does not fail silently.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are not providing `dataType` so jQuery makes an "intelligent guess" of what the content type is from the response `Content-Type` header which you said is `application/json`.

So jQuery treats the response as JSON which means it will try to automagically parse it as so, causing an error.

Because the request causes an error

```
$.parseJSON( "hello world" );
"Invalid JSON: hello world"
```

the success callback won't obviously be fired.

Answer (score 6):

Give this a rip:

```
$.ajax("/ajax_dummy", {
    dataType: "text",
    success: function() {
        console.log("winning.");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus); //error logging
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add this markup

```
<div id="error"></div>
```

then add this handler to catch AJAX errors

```
$("#error").ajaxError(function(event, request, settings){
  $(this).append("<li>Error requesting page " + settings.url + "</li>");
});
```

Alternatively, you could rewrite your original code like this

```
$.get('/ajax_dummy', function() { 
    alert('foo');  
}).error(function() {
    // catch error
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because according to the documentation the $.get() syntax should be like this

```
jQuery.get( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] [, dataType] )
```

please note the "**success**" callback option. a success callback called when the request is success based on status codes (200). but your url might be not a valid path or returns some other status code (404) meaning "file not found" and thus an error occurs. so success method never called.

also there is no "error" callback defined with your syntax. check the following more complete code

```
$.get("/ajax_dummy", function() { alert('foo'); })
  .error(function(d,e) { alert(e); })
  .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```